# insert into a table from a select query in oracle

Tags: oracle, select, insert

I am trying to insert the values of a select query which need to go into a column, into another table along with couple other columns something like below.
Data types for the columns.

col1-number, col2-number, col3-varchar, col4-date, col5-char(1),col6-char(1)

```
insert into table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7)
select ( uid, 22, 'HTML', sysdate,'null','null','N')
from ( select query here)
```

but when I run the above query I am getting an error - ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected near line 2 of the above query. Can anyone please point me what is wrong with this or if there is a better way to do it. thank you!

Comment: what is the data type of col1, ... col5? This error has to do with conversion to date using a date format model.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the complete `CREATE TABLE` statement for `table1`. Unrelated, but: the parentheses around the column list in the `select` part are totally useless.

Comment: Presumably `col1` is a date, and the subquery you haven't shown is returning a string which can't be implicitly converted to a date. You've changed and hidden so much though it's hard to tell what you're really doing. You have too many parentheses at the moment, for a start, which would cause ORA-00907 with what you've shown. It would be much easier if you showed your actual query and the table definition.

Comment: Or `col4` is of `CHAR`type :)

Comment: Added the columns types on the question. The subquery is returning numbers, which need to be inserted in col1. hope this makes sense. thanks

Comment: The subquery is a complex query joining multiple tables which outputs list of uids.

Comment: I figured this out, 'null' was causing the issue. I just inserted '', and it worked. thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

`'null'` is a string. Presumably either `col5` or `col6` is a number column, and we cannot cast that string to a number.

To insert no value into those columns use the `null` keyword like this:

```
insert into table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7)
select ( uid, 22, 'HTML', sysdate, null, null,'N')
from ( select query here)
```

Alternatively remove them from the insert projection:

```
insert into table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col7)
select ( uid, 22, 'HTML', sysdate, 'N')
from ( select query here)
```